# System.Management.Automation and System.Runtime.Remoting assembly

Tags: powershell

I have added the reference of Assemblies(System.Management.Automation and System.Runtime.Remoting) in my C# application and used the powershell interface in my project.
but during the compliation of the code,am geting an error saying

> "The type or namespace name 'Remoting'
>   does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Management.Automation'" The
>   type or namespace name 'PowerShell'
>   could not be found
>
> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll
>   System.Runtime.Remoting
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll

Comment: I think we need to know what using statement or full class name you're using that's causing the error ... I can't decide why it's talking about "the type or namespace name 'PowerShell'"

Answer (score 5):

For compilation you should be referencing the System.Management.Automation assembly at this location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

If you're looking for PowerShell remoting, you need to use the namespace System.Management.Automation.Remoting.  For the PowerShell type, you'll likely need the following using statements in your C# source code file:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```